# Specify number of time datamember can occur in the request header

Tags: wcf

In WCF is there a provision to have a layer of protection for a [datamember] variable, so that it occurs only a specific number of time in the request header.

So have a default value set for all data member variable names, rather than setting individual properties for maximum time each variable should occur in a request header. (This setting is basically to protect against say a brute force or a DDOS attack).

Any suggestions / pointers on the same would be great.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Comment: Anyone, any help or recommendations for the above?.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here, please elaborate ?